# Dart/Flutter Error: A value of type 'AuthSession' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'CognitoAuthSession'

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Our application requires to get the user role from **Cognito**, to solve this we followed the [this comment](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/413) but the *linter*(from **Android Studio**) and the running time show us the next bug:

```sh
[+10900 ms] [+10852 ms] lib/auth/infrastructure/auth.repository.dart:61:43: Error: A value of type 'AuthSession' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'CognitoAuthSession'.
[   +3 ms] [   +2 ms]  - 'AuthSession' is from 'package:amplify_auth_plugin_interface/src/Session/AuthSession.dart' ('/opt/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/amplify_auth_plugin_interface-0.1.1/lib/src/Session/AuthSession.dart').
[        ] [        ]  - 'CognitoAuthSession' is from 'package:amplify_auth_cognito/src/CognitoSession/CognitoAuthSession.dart' ('/opt/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/amplify_auth_cognito-0.1.1/lib/src/CognitoSession/CognitoAuthSession.dart').
[        ] [        ]       CognitoAuthSession fetchedSession = await _authCategory.fetchAuthSession(
[        ] [        ]                                           ^
```

The next is the repository's code where we are using **Amplify Auth**:

```dart
import 'package:amplify_auth_cognito/amplify_auth_cognito.dart';
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify.dart';
import 'package:amplify_flutter/categories/amplify_categories.dart';

class AmplifyAuthRepository implements AuthRepository {
  AmplifyAuthRepository({AuthCategory? authCategory})
      : _authCategory = authCategory ?? Amplify.Auth;

  final AuthCategory _authCategory;

@override
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchSession() async {
    try {
      CognitoAuthSession fetchedSession = await _authCategory.fetchAuthSession(
          options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true));
      String token = fetchedSession.userPoolTokens.idToken;
      Map<String, dynamic> payload = Jwt.parseJwt(token);
      // Access the groups
      List groups = payload['cognito:groups'];
      Map<String, dynamic> result = {
        'isSignedIn': fetchedSession.isSignedIn,
        'roles': groups
      };
      return result;
    } on AmplifyException catch (error) {
      // TODO: Catch error for analytics, not required for frontend.
      throw AmplifyException(error.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

It must be a `CognitoAuthSession` type variable in order to extract the session token and with it, to get the user's role(as you can see on the aforementioned comment).

For more details please visit this [issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/504).

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
  • Flutter version 2.0.4 at /opt/flutter
  • Framework revision b1395592de (7 days ago), 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
  • Engine revision 2dce47073a
  • Dart version 2.12.2
```

May i be using this wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of `amplify_flutter` and `amplify_auth_cognito` you are using?

Comment: @RaviSevta   ```amplify_analytics_pinpoint: ^0.1.1
 amplify_api: ^0.1.1
 amplify_auth_cognito: ^0.1.1
 amplify_flutter: ^0.1.1
 amplify_storage_s3: ^0.1.1```

Comment: had you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: @RaviSevta I did, i'm getting the error again.

Comment: actually, it's not producing an error on my machine, so it's a little bit hard to catch the exact error. @SalahAdDin

Comment: @RaviSevta It seems to be not validating `CognitoAuthSession` as a validad cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cast await _authCategory.fetchAuthSession response to CognitoAuthSession.

```
CognitoAuthSession fetchedSession =
        await _authCategory.fetchAuthSession(options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true)) as CognitoAuthSession;
    print('fetchedSession ${fetchedSession.userPoolTokens?.idToken}');
```

Comment: Yes, casting to sub class is how this is done in Dart. The cast will fail if the instance is not of the cast-to class. You can also assign to an `AuthSession` first an then use `if (session is CognitoAuthSession)`. Within the block controlled by the `if` statement the variable will be considered as `CognitoAuthSession` type.